# jquery progressbar not working

Tags: jquery

js code

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
      value: 37
    });
  });
```

html:

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<div id="percent"></div>
```

include files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<link href="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

i did almost everything, show on click, show on document ready, and i just can't get that progress bar to show up any ideas?

Comment: Why you have two files with **jQuery** (`jquery-1.9.1.js` & `jquery.js`)? What console says to you (any errors)?

Comment: [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/u9u4A/).check your js files links and console for errors .

Comment: the second include file is my js functions file, thx for the help, if not you i wouldn't notice that error till tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so i'll stop programming for today (haven't slept tonight), the css file was in the js folder, and i forgot to add js/ to the href.

Comment: Don't you use an IDE? Most webdev related IDE's (for example Aptana) provide autocomplete for these things, so you should find the problem quite easiliy.
Also, the use of developer tools would be handy. If you used the Chrome developer tools (or Opera Dragonfly, Firefox Firebug, ...) you would notice quite fast that the file could not be found, which gives you a direction of where the problem is situated.